# Website that aggregates definitions from multiple French dictionaries in one place

Tags: ressources, dictionnaires

I am looking for a website that gives definitions of French words but coming from different notorious dictionaries.

As an example, being able to search available definition for a term that could be defined differently, like “Biomasse”.

I'd like to visualize all definitions given by Larousse, LeRobert, L'Internaute, Wikitionnaire and many more at one place.

Comment: « L'auteur d'une oeuvre de l'esprit jouit sur cette oeuvre, du seul fait de sa création, d'un droit de propriété incorporelle exclusif et opposable à tous. » extrait du [Code de la propriété intellectuelle](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/section_lc/LEGITEXT000006069414/LEGISCTA000006114031/#LEGISCTA000006114031). C'est pour ça que tout ce qui n'est pas publié sous licence CC ne peut pas être reproduite librement.

Comment: You can fetch that stuff using simple shell scripting in Linux. Then trim it down using more simple commands etc. Get rid of those annoying ads on Larousse online.

Answer (score 5):

Commercial dictionaries would certainly object:

[Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/mentions-legales):

> Par conséquent, sauf autorisation de l’Editeur, l’utilisation de systèmes automatisés ou de logiciels pour extraire et collecter tout ou partie des Contenus du Site (en ce compris sa structure) de quelque façon que ce soit et à quelque fin que ce soit (notamment capture de données d’écran / « screen scraping », exploration et/ou fouille de données et/ou de textes, extraction de données et/ou de textes et récupération de données et/ou de textes, etc.) est interdite.

[Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/infos/cgu)

> Sous réserve des droits concédés ci-dessus à l'Utilisateur, il est notamment interdit de copier, reproduire, représenter, modifier et/ou exploiter, de quelque façon que ce soit et à quelque fin que ce soit, tout ou partie de la structure et du contenu du Site. A ce titre, sauf autorisation préalable et écrite de Larousse, l’Utilisateur ne peut pas procéder à la reproduction, représentation, adaptation, traduction et/ou transformation partielle ou intégrale, ou transfert sur un autre site web des éléments du Site et des ressources proposées au téléchargement.

Comment: Ces avertissements ne sont qu'un rappel de la [propriété intellectuelle](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/section_lc/LEGITEXT000006069414/LEGISCTA000006146349/) qui [remonte à quelques siècles en France](https://cours-de-droit.net/histoire-de-la-propriete-intellectuelle-a121606042/) et de [la loi](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/section_lc/LEGITEXT000006069414/LEGISCTA000006114031/#LEGISCTA000006114031).

Comment: @None Oui. Ce que je veux dire, c'est que ces deux dictionnaires n'ont pas de clauses qui assoupliraient cette règle alors qu'effectivement, le wiktionnaire ou le TFLi sont publiés avec une licence qui autorise les outils d'agrégation sous réserve que les sources y soient indiquées.

Comment: Effectivement, ça s'annonce mal avec ces clauses. merci